# Websocket Server Android

Tags: java, android, websocket

Does anyone know of a free/open source websocket server that can be used for android? A light-weight Java one (hopefully) would work as well.

Comment: I've used https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket with Android and it worked fine

Comment: this looks like what I need, pose it as a solution and I can accept it

Comment: http://jwebsocket.org/ may be also one.

Comment: i looked at that but it didn't seem tailored to my needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) is a good implementation. It handles the connections in threads, and is relatively easy to use and lightweight.

Comment: Are you able to connect this socket server in android from a HTML over WSS ?